# Recursive listing of directories and files C

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop, directory, stat

My C code for recursively listing directories and files get executed multiple times. I am not sure how to fix it and why it keeps happening... It is not infinite its just like 10 times shows the current directory.

```
void printdir(char *dir, int depth)
{
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *entry;
struct stat statbuf;
int spaces = depth;

dp = opendir(dir);
while((entry = readdir(dp)))  {
    lstat(entry->d_name,&statbuf);
    if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
        /* Found a directory, but ignore . and .. */
        if(strcmp(".",entry->d_name) == 0 ||
           strcmp("..",entry->d_name) == 0)
            continue;
        printf("%*s%s/\n",spaces,"",entry->d_name);
        /* Recurse at a new indent level */
        printdir(entry->d_name,depth+1);
    }
    else printf("%*s%s\n",spaces,"",entry->d_name);
}
closedir(dp);
}
int print_file(char *file, char *dir, struct stat buf, int showinode, int showlong, int showRec)
{
if (showinode)
    printf("%lld ", buf.st_ino);

if (showlong)
    print_long(file, dir, buf);

if (showRec)
    printdir(dir, 0);
else
    printf("%s\n", file);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to go through the trouble of `lstat(entry->d_name,&statbuf);` followed by `if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))`. As I mentioned in a comment to your prior post, it's sufficient to check `if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)`. The information is already in the `entry` structure.

Comment: Oh I see,,, let me delete it.

Comment: Still no luck, it repeats multiple times

Comment: @lurker that wasnt the reason, any more ideas?

Comment: The other issue is that you'll need to pass the entire path (or path relative to your starting directory) to `opendir`. Otherwise, it will continue to attemp to open each name from the top level directory. So if you have directories, `foo/bar` and `foo/bah`, then when you do `printdir('foo', 0)` what happens is `printdir` will recursively call `printdir('bar', 1)` (instead of `printdir('foo/bar', 1)`) and `printdir('bah', 1)` (instead of `printdir('foo/bah', 1)`. The path needs to be relative to the current directory or [change directories](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html).

Comment: @lurker But how do I do this? I tried this `dp = opendir(".");` and i changed here `if (showRec)
    printdir(".", 0);`

Comment: build a new path which is `dir` plus `/` plus `entry->d_name` and perform your recursive call on that rather than just on `entry->d_name`. Be careful to allocate enough characters to hold the new path.

Comment: @lurker: Or do the sane thing and use `openat()`, `fdopendir()`, `fstatat()`...

Comment: @EOF yep....  I was trying not to introduce more new functions to the OP, but yes. :)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do... while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}',  never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest 4 spaces per indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and still allows for many indent levels across the page

Comment: when calling system functions, especially those that access the hard disk, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @lurker: Well, you *really* don't want to copy around paths. It's bad enough that `readdir()` is actually *more* sane than `readdir_r()` due to poorly-specified maximum filepaths/names in POSIX.

Comment: @EOF yes, this is true.

Comment: @EOF so you think using `openat(), fdopendir(), fstatat()` will solve my problem?

Comment: @AnastasiaNetz If you use them correctly, yes.

Comment: @EOF Any suggestions on what to watch out for?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive function that lists the directories it comes across, using `openat()`, `fdopendir()`, `fstatat()` to avoid string-operations on paths (and, possibly, race-conditions on the directory-tree):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int sanerecursivedirsearch(int dirfd)
{
  DIR *curdir = fdopendir(dirfd);
  if (!curdir)
    {
      perror("fdopendir()");
      close(dirfd);
      return -1;
    }
  struct dirent *direp;
  while (!!(direp = readdir(curdir)))
    {
      if (!strcmp(direp->d_name, "..") || !strcmp(direp->d_name, "."))
        continue;
      struct stat statbuf;
      fstatat(dirfd, direp->d_name, &statbuf, 0);
      if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
        {
          int newfd = openat(dirfd, direp->d_name,
                             O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
          if (newfd == -1)
            {
              perror("openat()");
              continue;
            }
          printf("directory found:\t%s\n", direp->d_name);
          sanerecursivedirsearch(newfd);
        }
    }
  closedir(curdir);
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "insufficient command-line arguments");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  int fd = openat(AT_FDCWD, argv[1],
                  O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
  if (fd == -1)
    {
      perror("openat()");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  sanerecursivedirsearch(fd);
  return 0;
}
```